# Error in Delphi xe7 Android

Tags: android, delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe7

I have created some small application for Android using delphi XE7. And today when tried to compile that code it was giving the error which i have mentioned below:

> [DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot find -ldl.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What have you just changed?

Comment: I have not changed any of the settings. Is that any file is corrupted ?

Comment: Something has changed

Comment: Is there any solution..?

Comment: Don't you think that we need to identify the problem before moving on to devising a solution?

Comment: If you are quoting the error message correctly, that could mean that a file **dl.** cannot be found in a link step.

Comment: No. It's not showing the file name and if expand this error, there are lots of error are coming.

Comment: Yash, I same problem. This error because delphi installation does not complete install about rewrite path setting and search old or new android sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled XE7 and then i have installed Delphi XE7, then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar recently when creating a C++ application under Ubuntu using `ld`, when I had not installed all the libraries I needed.

`arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe` is the linker.

The `-l` Parameter used to specified the libraries to link, so what this is saying is that the linker can't find the `dl` library.

I suspect you have system path or project search path that has changed.

Comment: A path is changed for sure... I was in the same truoble when I've changed the SDK version manually...  Tools/ options/ SDK In NDK sheet, the last entry (Delphi NDK Library path) has two entrys, separated by ';' check the second path...

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, still no solution. and no, i haven´t changed any paths. just started the Computer the next day and tried to compile my Project again.hoping to get this fixed, because a complete reinatallation of Delphi xe 7 plus delphi SDKs takes some hours.

Comment: You can uninstall XE7 and don't uninstall Android SDK's. Then, while installing again, you remove the option for installing Android SDK and you can use the same old SDK's.

Comment: ok thanks, but installing Delphi takes about 3-4 hours on my computer and i´m not sure if the Problem will occur again, so fixing the root of it would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

If Library Paths are missing then this error comes.
[SDK Paths missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOgtp.png)

Try to Fillup these paths and you will be able to compile again.